# How to disable input method

Tags: input-method

By using `toggle-input-method`, I can disable input method when that is active.

But sometimes I just want to disable it regardless the input method status.
I couldn't find the function for it. How can I do it?

Comment: I don't understand. You can't *disable* it if it's not enabled. If it *is* enabled, `toggle-input-method` disables it. `(deactivate-input-method)` is what the toggle command calls when it disables it. That's a plain function rather than a command; but provided it's safe to call at any time, you could write a little wrapper command for it if you particularly want one.

Comment: Sorry, maybe that's matter of my poor English. I want to keep it disabled when it's disabled. In the case like this the word `disable` is not fit, right?  Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`M-x find-function toggle-input-method` to read its source code,

```
(defun toggle-off-input-method ()
  (interactive)
  (if current-input-method (deactivate-input-method)))
```